# How do I keep form input data between AJAX requests (Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have trouble understanding the way of handling dynamic form in rails.

Lets say I have ordinary **form** which is generated dynamically by user manipulations with the selects and checkboxes on the top of the page (another, stand-alone form). So parts of my form are showing up and disappearing with AJAX requests. What I need is storing already filled in fields so even if they are re-rendered, user sees what was put in already.

Example:

Table row before request:

```
Field1 | FieldBlah | Field234
_____________________________
value1 |           | value234
```

Then I get Ajax request and table is reloaded, so I get:

```
Field1 | FieldBlah | Field234 | FieldXXX
________________________________________
       |           |          |
```

with blank fields.

How do I keep data so User no longer needs re-write data into same fields?

Comment: When Feild1 and Field234 are changed to `value1` and `value234`, do you want to save those changes into the database on your server?  If so, then you should be calling an update action when the change is made by the user.  The update action can then re-render the relevant sections, with the updated data, so those changes will persist.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but there is a possibility that user will not save the item after he chooses few options but will just leave the page. so I will end up with lot of dummy, not useful records.

Comment: Lets say user selected something entered some value value1, value234. after this, is user moving/redirecting to some other page? Or he's restricted to stay in the same page ?

Comment: @Ajay he can leave page as well, no restrictions here. That's why I do not want save record right after first inputs, it can become useless

Comment: @Vla, How many such attribute/values combinations you are expected to carry ? I mean like 4/5 values or something more than 10-15 values ?

Comment: Have you considered only re-rendering the 'reactive' parts of your form? For example the AJAX request could return data for FieldBlah and FieldXXX at which point you could inject that new data into the existing form HTML.

Comment: @Ajay there can be up to 30 fields depending on user options choosen

Comment: @AdamWaselnuk this seems to be too hard, as items are also sorted basing by some other parameters, so I can not render each item, I need to re-render "parent" row each time

Comment: No problems, you can check my added answer of using cookies! This won't put any load on your server, this cookies is a part of localstorage!
store your data in cookies and use them when you reopen your form again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,you can carry forward your values in cookies. Cookies actually consists of a single name = value pair (both of name, pair must be text).

```
cookies["field_1"] = "value1"
cookies["field_234"] = "value_234"
```

If you just want to hold all the values (let's say you have got 10 fields and sequentially if you want to hold of all them) then you can do:

```
cookies['my_values'] = "#{value_1}_#{value_2}_#{value_3}_#{value_4}"
```

like this way, you can hold all 10values(may be blank value,if some field don't hold any value).
then while splitting use '_'(underscore) to separate values(10 fields).

Hope you find this useful :)

Comment: This may be a good use case for localStorage or sessionStorage. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Cookies will work just great here, thanks Ajay!

Another option I was suggested was using **serialize** to store data as a hash in parent object (if there is any, in my case I did).